# Can I schedule a boot volume backup by using python SDK in oci

Tags: python, sdk, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I need to automate the boot volume backup.that backup should overwrite the next backup.and latest 5 five backups should be store .can I do this by using python SDK in oci

I was trying but can't able to find solution.and can we do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can automate this workflow using Python SDK.

You can create a new backup using this API -> https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/api/#/en/iaas/20160918/VolumeBackup/CreateVolumeBackup

Here is the Python sample - [https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/api/#/en/iaas/20160918/VolumeBackup/CreateVolumeBackup:~:text=Java%20SDK-,Python,-SDK](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/api/#/en/iaas/20160918/VolumeBackup/CreateVolumeBackup:%7E:text=Java%20SDK-,Python,-SDK)

In the same script, you can list all the backups using this API -> https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/api/#/en/iaas/20160918/VolumeBackup/ListVolumeBackups

While listing you can order or sort and then you can count and delete until counter is 5. Here is the API to delete all the backups except the latest 5.

Hope this helps. Thanks.